# SmbException: A duplicate name exists on the network: how to prove that a few servers have the same DNS name

Tags: java, dns, smb, local-network

Need your advice about the following:

- We try to get file from another server in our local network by SMB
- When we call server by IP everything works file
- When we call server by DNS name we get an exception: jcifs.smb.SmbException: A duplicate name exists on the network

I googled the similar questions and found that it could happen when a few servers have the same DNS name.

Could you please advise me how to prove it to our network administrators? Because they say that it’s impossible and every server has the only DNS name in our local network.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe the problem is that two servers have the same NetBIOS name, not DNS name.

Comment: I believe you are right, but I still don't understand how to proove it...

Comment: If you tell your IT people it's the NetBIOS name it will make a difference in their response.

Answer (score 0):

You may also have a server which is registered under 2 different domains, and a program which tries to access this server without mentioning a domain.
If such is the case, if you enter:

```
nslookup <server>.<expected domain>
```

you may get:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <server>.<expected domain, for instance your company's domain>
Address: <IP>
```

And if you enter:

```
nslookup <server>
```

(note that you did not mention any domain) you may get:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <server>.<UNexpected domain #2>
Address: <IP>
```

If this is the case, we have to unregister your server from the unexpected domain and everything should go back to normal.